# Rspec test fails with nil before_create fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a number of fields that are set in my model using the before_create filter

```
  before_create :generate_word_count!, :generate_character_count!

  private

  def generate_word_count!
    self.word_count = get_word_count(self)
  end

  def generate_character_count!
    self.character_count = get_character_count(self.source_text)
  end
```

When I run my Rspec test, the fields that are created using before_create come back as nil in the reponse. However, I have tested them via Postman and there is no issue.

```
before(:each) do
        @valid_annotation_list = FactoryGirl.attributes_for_list :annotation, 5
        post :create, {article: @article.id, annotations: @valid_annotation_list }, format: :json
        @annotation_response = json_response
      end
```

Are my Rspec tests skipping these fields somehow?

Comment: Please include the actual test, as well as your controller code for `create`

Comment: I would use an `before_save` or `after_validate` callback instead - the word count will not be updated when editing an existing record if you use `before_create`